# Sci Fi book about xenoarchaeology and a beetle like culture

Tags: story-identification, books, space-exploration

Circa late 60s, 70s, or early 80s, written in English.

A group of Xenoarchaeologists are exploring ruins on a distant planet. The inhabitants were beetle like. One researcher (mentally unstable?) builds a robot beetle so he can better understand the culture.  His conclusion was that they became 'bankrupt' because of inbreeding.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if the questions there prompt further details that you can edit into your question. I made a few small modifications to your question to try to improve clarity. Let me know if I made a wrong assumption about what you were saying.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Total Eclipse](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41087.Total_Eclipse)*, by John Brunner.

[image: Total Eclipse - book cover]

> In 2020, an international space team, exploring Sigma Draconis, 19 light years from earth, discovers the remains of a highly advanced society that has left behind its most spectacular artifact; the largest telescope imaginable, carved & polished from a natural moon crater. Successive space crews determine that the native culture evolved & disappeared mysteriously after a mere 3000 years of existence. It's now 2028. Another mission reaches the planet with just one goal--to discover why the civilization disappeared--& with just one hope--that this knowledge will prevent the same thing from happening on earth.

I no longer have a copy, but I distinctly remember that line about going bankrupt.

If I recall correctly, the government didn't trust scientists and sent along a South American (?) army officer with a Stone Age mentality who continuously got in the way. After a chapter or two, however, he came round to seeing their point of view.

Comment: I remember the SFBC offering this when it first came out but I didn't get it because I didn't know Brunner.  Now I want to read it! This is why I like story ID questions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, one warning: a lot of Brunner's books are big fat downers.  The quality is also surprisingly variable; some are very good, some not so much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have, over the years, read many John Brunner books but forgot about this one.  Set in 2020 - how far away that once seemed!!!  Will now go searching the bookshelves.  Again, thank you. Bryan